# Install new font programantically from Flash / ActionScript

Tags: flash, actionscript, fonts

Is it possible to programantically install a new font in the system from a flash file embedded in a website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. The only thing you can do is to politely ask the user to download the file and install it.

Why do you need this? If just to display your content in the way you designed it just embed the font in your Flash application.

Comment: It's a long story, but I need the font to really be installed in the user's system, not just for the Flash application.